# How would I disable a button with the context value

Tags: python, django

How would I use the context value to check if the currently logged in user has the same team and it's not null and the is_edit field is true.

{% if request.user.is_edit and team==request.user.team%}

produces

```
Could not parse the remainder: '==request.user.team' from 'team==request.user.team'
```

edit.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Add{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1 class="cardHeader">Edit Page</h1>
<div class="card">

    <div class="container">
    <h1>Edit team member</h1>
        <p>Edit contact info,location and role</p>
    </div>
    <form method = "POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ editProfileForm.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" name="editProfileForm" value="Save">
        <!-- Check if the user who can delete the team member is the same team and had admin role?  -->
        {% if request.user.is_edit and team==request.user.team%}
            <input type="submit" name="deleteProfileForm" value="Delete">
        {% endif %}
    </form> 

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
def edit(request,user_id):
    context={}
    try:
        user = Profile.objects.get(id=user_id)
        print(user,user_id)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        return redirect('home')
    context['team']=user.team
    #Currently logged in user has to have is_edit? and be the same team
    #if request.user.team != user.team and request.user.is_edit:
        #return redirect('home')
    
    if request.method=="POST":
        if "editProfileForm" in request.POST:
            print('Editing')
            edit_profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None,instance=user)
            if edit_profile_form.is_valid(): 
                edit_profile_form.save()
                print(edit_profile_form)
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                context['editProfileForm'] = edit_profile_form
                return render(request,'edit.html',context)
        if "deleteProfileForm" in request.POST:
            print('Deleting')
            try:
                user.delete()
                #messages.success(request, "The user is deleted")            

            except Exception as e:
                #messages.error(request, "User does not exist")   
                print(str(e)) 
                pass

            return redirect('home')
       
    else:
        edit_profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None,instance=user)
        context['editProfileForm'] = edit_profile_form
    return render(request,'edit.html',context)
```

Comment: Add spaces around the operator - `team == request.user.team`

Comment: Still makes it empy. But the error is gone.

Comment: I see you have `user.team` where `user = Profile.objects.get(id=user_id)`, are you sure `request.user` is an instance of `Profile`?

Comment: print(user.team, request.user.team)->Team object (6ab326b7-6fa0-48ea-8a85-5f36c32635cc) does produce the right value.

Comment: request.user.is_edit didn't work until I passed it from the view as a context value.